# Enable cors in wcf - ajax

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, cors

I am a beginner in WCF, I have been attempting to enable CORS for a WCF service hosted in my IIS. I have gone through several posts and Stack Overflow questions, and all answers are leading me to different solutions and none of them works.

Can someone explain me how to achive this? I tried creating a global.asax and adding begin_request event to set up the headers, but it changed nothing.
This is what I used:

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
```

Where should I start for this and which is the best way for achieving this?

Comment: have you tried this http://enable-cors.org/server_wcf.html ?

Comment: @MajoB Yes but i am not able to properly configure it, Its giving me lot of exceptions

Comment: Have you added `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to the web config

Comment: And what are those exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

I assume WCF service is up and running.Fix in **Web.config** .Add below section in **system.webServer** section.

```
<httpProtocol>
<customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1728000" />
</customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

**Caution**

---

***NOTE! The Access-Control-Allow-Origin setting is set to a value of `"*"`. This will allow all callers to have access. You can specify only your caller.***

From your existing implementation it should work.However I have slightly tweaked the code and it works for me.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin" , "*");
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS" )
{    
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods" , "GET, POST" );
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Origin, Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With");
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000" );
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
}
```